# Javascript object proccesing confusion

Tags: javascript, json

I am at freecodecamp.com and stuck at a problem of Profile Lookup.What I am missing here? can anyone point me out ? If I comment out this condtion `firstName == contacts[i].firstName` it is returning 4 times **No such contact** & 1 time **No such property** what I am doing wrong?

**Use cases :**

```
 - "Kristian", "lastName" should return "Vos" 
 - "Sherlock", "likes" should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]  
 - "Harry","likes" should return an array 
 - "Bob", "number" should return "No such contact"  //**fails**
 - "Akira","address" should return "No such property"

    var contacts = [

        {
            "firstName": "Akira",
            "lastName": "Laine",
            "number": "0543236543",
            "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Harry",
            "lastName": "Potter",
            "number": "0994372684",
            "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Holmes",
            "number": "0487345643",
            "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Kristian",
            "lastName": "Vos",
            "number": "unknown",
            "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
        }
     ];

      function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
      // Only change code below this line
       for(var i = 0; i< contacts.length;i++){

         if(firstName == contacts[i].firstName && 
               contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){

             return contacts[i][prop];
         }

         /*if(firstName == contacts[i].firstName){
            return "No such contact" ;
         }*/ 

        if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false){
           return "No such property";  
        }

       }
      }

       //test strings
       console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
       console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"));
       console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
       console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number"));
       console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address"));
```

Comment: just a misplaced return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move

```
return "No such contact";
```

to the end of the function, because all checks took place and have something valuable returned. But if not, then the contact is not in the array.

```js
var contacts = [{ firstName: "Akira", lastName: "Laine", number: "0543236543", likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"] }, { firstName: "Harry", lastName: "Potter", number: "0994372684", likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"] }, { firstName: "Sherlock", lastName: "Holmes", number: "0487345643", likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"] }, { firstName: "Kristian", lastName: "Vos", number: "unknown", likes: ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"] }];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (firstName == contacts[i].firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        }
        if (!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
    return "No such contact"; // move to the end of the function
}

//test strings
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```